# Rails 4: Generate function from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to be able to form this function from params:

```
MindBody::Services::ClientService.get_sales(data)
```

where `ClientService` can be several different things, and `get_sales(data)` can be several different things. How can I take params and insert them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you look for a way to dynamically choose a module and a method?

```
module_name = :ClientService
method_name = :get_sales
MindBody::Services.const_get(module_name).send(method_name, data)
```

Comment: one thing, I think it should be `const_get(module_name)` not `const_get(module)`